# Transition a chart dependent on another chart

Tags: d3.js, transition

I am new to d3.js but have managed to make two individual charts as in introduction.
I have a map chart, which has dots representing monitoring stations.
I also have a line chart which has multiple timeseries (data from json) from one monitoring station.

What I would like to do.  Have the two charts on one page.  When you mouseover or click on a station on the map the data is loaded and displayed on the line chart.  When a new station is selected on the map, the data transitions on the line chart

The question I have is one of style.  With the two separate charts what is the best way to combine them?
With the transition, I have searched but have not found any simple examples that has two charting elements where interacting with one effects the other.  Should I combine all the timeseries data into one json file (say 4 timeseries times 50 stations) or have 50 json files?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your timeseries data is very large, I would just put everything in one JSON file to make things simpler and so that changing stations can take place entirely client side.